# Use Common Table Expression with Pony ORM

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, ponyorm

I have the following query that contains a common table expression:

```sql
WITH example AS (
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) as col
)
SELECT *
FROM example
```

Trying to use it in `database.select(query)` throws `pony.orm.dbapiprovider.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WITH"`, and `database.select(raw_sql(query))` throws `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.

How can I select data using a CTE with ponyorm?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use a query containing a CTE, call the `execute` function on the database and fetch the rows with the returned cursor:

```py
cursor = database.execute("""
    WITH example AS (
        SELECT unnest(ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) as col
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM example
""")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Note: The cursor is a class from [`psycopg2`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html), so while this solution does use the pony library the solution may differ depending on the database being used.